# My AVD emulator doesn't get loaded in Windows 8.1

Tags: android-emulator

**How can I load my AVD Emulator using Android Studio?**

I have **Windows 8.1** + **4gb RAM** + **Android Studio 1.5.**

Also I created AVD Like **API22 + 2gb RAM + x86** + Without( *Host and Snapshot ChechBox-Checked*).

So please Helps Me.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial from official website http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Comment: Also try This....But till can not start my AVD.....http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

And what error appears?

In Android Studio there is special "Run" section where you can view messages from your emulator (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMRXV.jpg).

Also you can view the process named "emulator-x86" in Task Manager. On the first run it takes time to allocate 2GB of memory. Emulator window may appear after 5 minutes since launch.

Comment: I can't show "emulator-x86" process in my Task Manager. and How to allocate 2GB of memory ? I have ADB 32-bit.

Comment: May be this is the cause of the problem? You can try to set 1GB. I'm also have such configuration - x86 with 1GB RAM.